# How to create search text box in jsp?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, performance, jsp

How to implement when i enter some any name in text box it will fetch the data from mysql database and show all related words in JSP page as textbox list.
when a text is entered in the box then related text should be displayed as a list by fetching from database.
when displayed text list selected, relevant action should be performed with that selection.
i got this code  from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but it is not working on my pc
Thanks in Advance.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags">
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [<? while($results=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE"))){ echo     "'".$result->Field."', "; } ?>];
$( '#ID' ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
});
});
```

so it works for me in my scripts